# WinAPI - GetLastError always returns 0 when called via a COM ATL DLL

Tags: c++, dll, vbscript, getlasterror

In my Windows API wrapper ATL dll, I have exposed `GetLastError` to COM for Windows API error handling.

It is implemented as below:

```C++
STDMETHODIMP CWinAPI::WinAPI_GetLastError(int *Result) {

    *Result = (int)GetLastError();

    return S_OK;
}
```

When I use it from VBScript like:

```VBScript
Dim WINAPI: Set WINAPI = WScript.CreateObject("WinAPIWrapperLib.WINAPI")

WINAPI.WinAPI_ShellExecute NULL, "", "NonExistentFile.exe", "", "", 1
WScript.Echo CStr(WINAPI.WinAPI_GetLastError)
```

*This must generate the `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error, but when I call this windows API function from my wrapper dll via VBScript, it always returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`.*

But when I add following lines to my implementation for `WinAPI_ShellExecute` like this:

```
DWORD ErrorMessageID = ::GetLastError();

wchar_t ErrorID[1024];

swprintf_s(ErrorID, 1024, L"%d", ErrorMessageID);

MessageBox(nullptr, (LPCWSTR)&ErrorID, L"GetLastError", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_DEFBUTTON1);
```

It correctly generates the error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

I like to know what goes wrong with `GetLastError`.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> Functions executed by the calling thread set this value by calling the
>   SetLastError function. You should call the GetLastError function
>   immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call
>   will return useful data. That is because some functions call
>   SetLastError with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code
>   set by the most recently failed function.

The problem is: you could not guarantee, that `GetLastError` is called immediately after `ShellExecute`. There is much going on between that calls - COM marshalling, VBScript calls, etc that most certainly affects thread last error flag. In fact you should not use `GetLastError` in the VBScript altogether:

> Visual Basic:  Applications should call err.LastDllError instead of
>   GetLastError.

Comment: Thank you, but AutoIt also have those functions implemented. When I use AutoIt like above, calling a WinAPI Function using `Dllcall` and then getting last error by a separate `Dllcall`, it correctly returns the last error.Why that?

Comment: Most likely it caches error code internally after each API method call.

Comment: Thanks, I will also do the same and notify you what happens.